# Get data from Google Cloud Firestore

Tags: xamarin.forms, google-cloud-firestore

[![I am unable to pass data of collection and document from android project to **PCL**,the way I tried threw null reference exception please help me with that.
Thanks

Android project to get data

```
   FirestoreDb firestore = FirestoreDb.Create("iyf-raipur");
    public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> GetCouncelorsAsync()
    {
        Query preachers = firestore.Collection(nameof(T));
        QuerySnapshot snapshots = await preachers.GetSnapshotAsync();
        foreach(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot in snapshots.Documents)
        {
            T data = documentSnapshot.ConvertTo<T>();
            System.Console.WriteLine();
        }

        return (IEnumerable<T>)preachers;

    }
```

**PCL ViewModel Code**

```
     private ObservableCollection<Preacher> preachers;
    private IRepository<Preacher> _repository = DependencyService.Get<IRepository<Preacher>>();
    public PreacherViewModel()
    {
        Preachers = new ObservableCollection<Preacher>();
        PopulatePreachers();
    }

    async void PopulatePreachers()
    {
        try
        {
            var list = await _repository.GetPreachersAsync();
            foreach (var preacher in list)
            {
                Preachers.Add(preacher);
                name = preacher.Name;
                email = preacher.Email;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

           await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("ERROR", ex.Message, "ok");
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Which line throws the NullRef exception?

Comment: Did you use the `DependencyAttribute` to register the implementation of the `IRepository` interface ?

Comment: Thanks for the response I forgot to that, I applied the dependency attribute but I got another exception saying "Exception has been thrown by target of invocation" how can I resolve this?

Comment: You could make a breakpoint to see which line throws the exception.

Comment: I got that exception on the line where i call dependency service to get IRepository.

Comment: Show the implementation of IRepository<Preacher> on Android, complete with DependencyAttribute.

Comment: I checked the inner exception I found that it is not able to find the json file even though its on android project on MainActivity.cs I set string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory+ 
@"json file"; Environment.SetEnvironmentVariablee("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS",path);

Comment: I set build action to Content but compiler says build action content is not supported.

Comment: Do you mean it is not able to find the `google-services.json` file ?You should set its build action to `GoogleServicesJson`.You could look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/push/migration/xamarin-android#3-google-servicesjson.

Comment: I am adding service account json file to solution,as mentioned in Google cloud firestore documentation.

Comment: Hey there, could you please tell me if you were able to solve this?

Comment: Yes i found why it was causing error, actually it was because i have not enabled the realtime database on firebase,so i enabled it and issue resolved but later I shifted to cloud firestore